# EditText and focus

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Whats the simplist way to implement a `EditText` that loses focus consistently?

I've run into a problem where an `EditText` isn't able to lose focus which gives me no way to indicate when to remove the soft keyboard, this is by design as I understand it.

My current application state is an `Activity` with 2 `Fragments` side-by-side and a `Toolbar` along the top, in the right side `Fragment` I have a `RecyclerView` which contains an `EditText` field, when I click/tap on the `EditText` a soft keyboard appears, this is working as intened.

The problem is that whenever I try to click/tap on any other `View` the focus on the `EditText` persists and I am therefore unable to hide the soft keyboard when the focus changes.

I am only able to set another `View` to have focus if I do the following on every `View` in the `Fragment`;

```
v.setOnClickListener {
    v.isFocusable = true
    v.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    v.requestFocus()
}
```

This doesn't help if a user clicks/taps on the other `Fragment` or the `Toolbar`, I would have to add this method to every `View` in the `Activity` for this behvaiour to propagate. This seems like an incredibly inefficient way to handle my problem.

Is there something simple that im missing to enable transfering of focus on `EditText` `Views`?

Comment: there is some kind of root layout in activity right? what if you focus that when you want EditText to lose focus? but you need to make it focusable ofc at first

Comment: @BachoKurtanidze I cant seem to set an onClick event to the root element. Clicking doesn't trigger any console messages..

Comment: have you tried to set its focusable, clickable and focusableInTouchMode attributes to true?

Comment: @BachoKurtanidze i didn't have clickable, i have added it though and still nothing

Comment: android:focusableInTouchMode="true" should do this right?

Comment: @Android_id that property on its own only seems to allow the `View` to gain focus you still have to `requestFocus()` it seems.

Comment: @glend okay . if the edittext is inside recyclerview  should try adding android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" not sure if this works. Please try

Comment: @Android_id add that to which `View`?

Comment: @glend recyclerview

Comment: @Android_id didn't work.

Comment: @glend is this added to activtiy manifest android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: @Android_id, i added it, nothing changed